# Error: Cannot install into directories with spaces

Tags: anaconda

Apologies if this question has been raised already.
I am trying to install **Anaconda** and this is the file `Anaconda3-2022.05-Linux-x86_64`. However when I try to specify a different directory for my installation I gets this error.

```
ERROR: Cannot install into directories with spaces
```

These are the commands.

```
Anaconda3 will now be installed into this location:
/home/gelsyt/anaconda3

  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify a different location below

[/home/gelsyt/anaconda3] >>> /media/gelsyt/New Volume/Ubuntu HDD/Applications
ERROR: Cannot install into directories with spaces
```

I understand that this is because of the spaces from the  "**New Volume**" & "**Ubuntu HDD**", I'm just wondering is there anyway to bypass this or allow this?

Comment: Hacky, but installing to a softlinked location without spaces might work.

Comment: The reason I need to install it on a different path is because I need to have the anaconda files on my HDD because I'm running low on my SSD which ubuntu is installed. So I tried specifying the path inside my HDD.

Comment: Did you try softlinking? `ln -s '/path/that has/spaces' /softlink/path` Then install to the softlink path. Also, if space is the issue, be sure to set the `envs_dirs` and `pkgs_dirs` to point on your external drive, otherwise you'll be writing to user home.

Comment: Hi! how would I actually do that? Where shall I enter the command? also how do I point it to external drive? sorry

Comment: You mean the configuration variables? That’s covered in the documentation: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the Disk Utility Provided by ubuntu. For Ubuntu 15.10. Search Disks in the Dashboard. Open Disks-> Click on the settings of the required hard drive.-> Edit File System->change the required name.

([Credits](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74542/is-there-a-way-to-rename-an-external-hard-drive/710487#710487))